# converting printout out char in return statement

Tags: java, string, char

cannot use array 
just want to print out convert or what convert would say after the if statement as a return

cannot use .toCharArray

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    System.out.println(ConvertToL33t("cow life" ));
}

public static String ConvertToL33t (String s)
{

    String max= s;
    System.out.println(max);
    char convert = (char) s.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < max.length(); i++){
        switch(convert){

        case 'e':
            convert = '3';
            break;
        case 'o':
            convert  = '0';
            break;
        case 'l':
            convert = '1';
            break;
        case 't':
            convert = '7';
            break;
        case 'a':
            convert = '4';
            break;
        }
    }
return convert;
```

Comment: I cannot parse the English in the first line. Please rephrase.

Comment: I don't see an `if` statement... do you mean the `switch`?

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, you can't just replace a letter in the same string. You will have to construct a new string, based on the previous string. One way to do this is by iterating over every character in the old string and adding it to a new string while replacing the characters you want.

It is advised to use a `StringBuilder` because it is a lot more efficient with the constant concatenation.

Try something along these lines:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(char convert : s.toCharArray()){
  switch(convert){
        case 'e':
            sb.append("3");
            break;
        case 'o':
            sb.append("0");
            break;
        case 'l':
            sb.append("1");
            break;
        case 't':
            sb.append("7");
            break;
        case 'a':
            sb.append("4");
            break;
        }
}

return sb.toString();
```

Comment: +1 for answering ONLY the question asked and leaving the rest as a learning experience :-)

Comment: i cant use an array thats the problem

Comment: @user3015113: the mothership doesn't allow me to use my mindreading abilities outside of lifethreatening situations, sorry. -Actually: construct it yourself! Loop over the string and use `charAt()` to get the current character. Basically just combine your post with my answer and you're good.